# What was Valkyrie referring to when Seiya stopped her from saying it in episode 9 of Shinchou Yuusha?

Tags: cautious-hero

I just watched *Shinchou Yuusha* episode 9 and there was a point where Valkyrie was referring to something like "you will worn out..." and then "I see so you've already caught on".

What was she referring to? The manga is a lot behind the anime, and I can't get a physical copy of the light novel in where I live, and can't find this answered in any discussion threads.

I don't mind the spoilers at all, since someone who searches this exact thing is looking for spoilers in the first place.

Comment: FYI, it's at 12:28 in the episode. The first part is, "You've worn out your...". The phrase usually is "you've worn out your welcome." Seiya puts a sword to her throat cutting her short. Later Seiya says "There's no need to say that now." (He could have been talking to Valkyrie or Rista). Valkyrie then says says "Ho, so you've caught on."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that both Valkyrie and Seiya realize that he’s come as far as he can through training alone. His stats might be at their max and he hasn’t gained any of the legendary equipment. Now he is trying to gain more powerful skills and since Valkyrie is the strongest god shown he of course turns to her. Valhalla Gate seems extremely powerful and would kill any human but if it killed the demon lord would it be worth Seiya’s life?

Comment: exactly what i was guessing...

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps Valkyrie is not a god (maybe demi) and therefore Seiya should be able to use her techniques. I came to this conclusion because I did not see any of the other gods bleed before. I could be wrong though since I did not bother to double check the previous episodes.

Comment: hmm could be right maybe that's the reason they appeared to have sex, when it is forbidden