# Were Valkyrie and Seiya caught having sex or training?

Tags: cautious-hero

In Episode 9 of *Cautious Hero*, were Seiya and Valkyrie caught having sex or were they actually training? How did Seiya learn that move? Did Valkyrie transfer it into him, or was she actually able to teach Seiya how to do the "Gate of Valhalla" move? Then, when the goddess Rista came in, Seiya tried stopping Valkyrie from saying something; what was it?

Comment: Might be related: [What was Valkyrie referring to when Seiya stopped her from saying it in episode 9 of Shinchou Yuusha?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/56036/2516)